# jQuery: Deleted the second matched element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

how would it be possible to delete the second fieldset by using jQuery? Is there a possibility?

```
<form class="form-validate form-horizontal" id="member-registration">
  <fieldset>...</fieldset>
  <fieldset>DELETE THESE FIELDSET</fieldset>
  <div class="form-actions"></div>
</form>
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you tried anything? This seems quite trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `:eq` selector along with `.remove()`:

```
$('fieldset:eq(1)').remove()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$('fieldset').nextAll().remove()` to delete all fieldset tags except the first one.